# How can I remove Eclipse Mars Jboss Tools Toolbar item

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars, jboss-tools

I have installed Eclipse Mars and have also installed the Jboss Tools from the eclipse marketplace.

My issue is that after installing the JBoss tools, I seem to have a set of controls for the server in my menu bar, that have been created in the Early Learning Centre style.  I've tried the Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective menu option, but still I am left with this awful menu.  Does anyone know how to stop it from showing on my toolbar?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, After some more specific searching, I found the answer at this link:

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/263510?start=0&tstart=0

specifically

> "To disable the new Launch Bar, select Window > Preferences >
>   Run/Debug > Launching > Launch Bar > uncheck [ ] Enable the Launch
>   Bar."

and it works a charm!

Comment: Eated up about 2 lines of previous eclipse menus. After some research finally found out how to remove this aweful big icons. thank you for your hint!