# Remove part of toolbar eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using eclipse mars under linux mint.

I wish to remove from the toolbar the line with the thee buttons blue green red etc..
Since the same commands are included in other bar which use much less space. 
[image: giant toolbar]

Is there any way to do that? I don't want to hide the entire toolbar to remove it.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the JBoss toolbar - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/34765697/2670892

Comment: Thanks, It works. I did not the toolbar name

Comment: @JonahGraham Thank you for the nomination, but I think I prefer to stay fairly anonymous. Thanks again.

Comment: OK I will let Foundation know and I will delete these off topic posts now that you have seen it. PS Feel free to get in touch with me if you ever want to drop your anonymity and/or are looking for Eclipse work.